# What is the motivation behind naming identity matrix as "eye"?

Tags: matlab

Matlab, as well as some other PLs (e.g. Python's numpy package) use "eye" as a function name for creation of the identity matrix. Why is that so?

Comment: isn't it just to avoid a single letter like "I" for a built-in?

Comment: @postmortes, maybe. But I'm personally seeing this "eye" as a biological organ. Perhaps that is because I'm not a native English speaker. I just wonder

Comment: ah, "eye" is sometimes used to 'spell' I in English; Similarly h is 'spelled' aitch, and f is spelled eff.  Probably not something you'd know if you weren't a native speaker though

Comment: @postmortes, don't you want to post that as an answer please?

Comment: @postmortes Not to mention the *em rule* (—) and *en rule* (–) in typography, which are the width of the letters *M* and *N* respectively.

Comment: @timtfj, could you please tell me more specifically how that is connected with my question and where I can read more about that?

Comment: i is often used to represent the imaginary unit $\mathrm i = \sqrt {-1}$. If you write a function that generates $I$, the identity matrix, then clearly you cannot use "i" again, since it is occupied. So this is a work around, to use "eye" to indicate the identity matrix by using the same pronunciation as the letter "I".

Comment: @JDoe There is an "alphabet" of spelt-out letter names, some more commonly used than others. *Eye* is one of them, and some like *em* and *en*  have become established words for things.

Comment: That's all is great. But could someone write that to the answer please? :)

Comment: @JDoe Everything I've found suggests that *eye* is cheating a bit. eg https://grammarist.com/spelling/letter-names/ The WordReference forums would be a good place to ask.

Comment: @timtfj, that's good but I've already asked the question here, so... :)

Comment: @JDoe They'll know more about the language aspects, and there'll be no risk of people closing the discussion down as off-topic. Answerers will be able to go into as much language detail as they want.

Comment: John Lawler, a fairly respectable linguist, gives the list here ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.usage.english/LZRjRbMHPe8 ) in a 1996 usenet post.  
@JDoe if I get any time at all this afternoon I'll pull this all together into an answer, but I expect someone will beat me to it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Matlab, i is treated as a function (see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html ) returning the imaginary unit $\sqrt{-1}$.  To avoid confusion with that, **eye** is used to represent the unit matrix.  I couldn't find any documentation on the mathworks site explaining the choice, but the likely answer is that it's because **eye** is used in English as a way to spell the name of the letter 'I'.

The 'spelling-names' for English letters are given by John Lawler in this post (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.usage.english/LZRjRbMHPe8 ), and listed below for convenient reference.

```
 a  /e/       A [cap preferred]
 b  /bi/      B [ditto; 'bee' more common than 'be']
 c  /si/      C [  ", 'see'; but 'C-note' and 'cee-note' both occur]
 d  /di/      dee
 e  /i/       ee or E
 f  /ef/      ef, or eff ['you effing idiot!']
 g  /ji/      gee ['jee' is possible but not recommended]
 h  /ec^/     aitch [the 't' seems to be required]
 i  /ay/      I or aye, occasionally 'eye'; cf 'eye-dialect'
 j  /je/      jay
 k  /ke/      kay
 l  /El/      el, or ell
 m  /Em/      em [cf em-dash]
 n  /En/      en [cf en-dash]
 o  /o/       oh or owe ['ow' makes more sense but is already /aw/]
 p  /pi/      P ['pee' is less common, because of its vulgar homophone]
 q  /kyu/     queue, or cue [not recommended]`
 r  /ar/      are? ar? ahr? arr?  nothing looks good; use R
 s  /es/      es or ess
 t  /ti/      tee
 u  /yu/      you, or yoo
 v  /vi/      vee [delta-vee, or dee-vee]
 w  /d@b@lyu/ double-u or doubleyou
 x  /Eks/     ex  [shorter to spell than to pronounce!]
 y  /way/     why, or wye
 z  /zi/      zee [US usage; elsewhere zed]
Spelling the letter names is not frequent enough in written English to be standard.  There's 
lots of variation.
```

As noted in both John Lawler's list and **timtfj**'s comment, some of the letter names have taken on lives of their own, with em- and en-dash occuring in printing and denoting the width of a capital M or capital N in the chosen font.